# When and why does a *.xlsx File contain a *.bin file?

Tags: excel, vba, security

I am currently working on a project to evaluate whether an uploaded `*.xlsx` file really is a `*.xlsx` file only and not a `*.xlsm` with changed extension.

Since a `*.xlsx` file is more or less a `*.zip` file, I extracted the contents and noticed that some files contain a `*.bin` file, while others don't. Although the excel file might be a legit one without any attempt to inject another extension by tricking the user into renaming it.

Therefore my question: When does a `xlsx` file contain a `*.bin` file? And is this method suitable to detect whether a `xlsx` file contains macros?

I am also checking the content of the `[content_types].xml` file to contain either one of the strings: `application/vnd.ms-office.vbaproject` and `application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroenabled`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When does a xlsx file contain a *.bin file?

Well, bin files are created not only workbooks which have macros but for workbooks which have OLE objects embedded in them.

Try this. Create a new workbook and click on `Developer Tab | Insert ActiveX control - Say Commandbutton`. Save and close the file as `.xlsx`. Rename to `.Zip` and check the zip file

[image]

**Edit**:

And yes sometimes to store the printer settings as well. Did a quick search and came across [THIS](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15216/Office-2007-bin-file-format) link

Extract from the above link in case the link dies.

In addition to VBA projects and embedded OLE objects, we find BIN parts in Excel 2007 .XLSB files for the following reasons :

1. Workbook part workbook.bin (MIME type: application/vnd.ms-excel.workbook)
2. Styles dictionary part styles.bin (MIME type: application/vnd.ms-excel.styles)
3. For each worksheet,

   **a.** an index part worksheets/binaryIndexxx.bin (MIME type: application/vnd.ms-excel.binIndexWs)

   **b.** a worksheet part worksheets/sheetxxx.bin (MIME type: application/vnd.ms-excel.worksheet)

   **c.** an optional printer settings part printerSettings/printerSettingsxxx.bin (MIME type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.printerSettings)
4. Optional calculation chain part calcChain.bin (MIME type: application/vnd.ms-excel.calcChain)
5. Optional comments parts commentsxxx.bin (MIME type: application/vnd.ms-office.legacyDrawing)
6. Optional tables parts tables/tablexxx.bin (MIME type: application/vnd.ms-excel.table)
7. Optional connections parts connections.bin (MIME type: application/vnd.ms-excel.connections)
8. Optional Chartsheet, Dialogsheet, Macrosheet parts (chartsheets/sheetxxx.bin, dialogsheets/sheetxxx.bin, macrosheets/sheetxxx.bin) (MIME type: application/vnd.ms-excel.chartsheet, application/vnd.ms-excel.dialogsheet, application/vnd.ms-excel.macrosheet)
9. Optional Pivot Table parts (pivotTables/pivotTablexxx.bin) (MIME type: application/vnd.ms-excel.pivotTable)
10. Optional Pivot Table Cache definition and records parts (pivotCache/pivotCacheDefinitionxxx.bin, pivotCache/pivotCacheRecordsxxx.bin) (MIME type: application/vnd.ms-excel.pivotCacheDefinition, application/vnd.ms-excel.pivotCacheRecords)
11. Optional Query tables (queryTables/queryTablexxx.bin) (MIME type: application/vnd.ms-excel.queryTable)

Comment: The link is good source, thanks! So I guess, it's legit to only accept the printerSettings and if the file contains anything else than these, deny it. You also cannot store VBA in the printerSettings, it throws an error when opening the file and removing the whole printerSettings context.

Comment: If you are worried about malicious code the set the macro setting in File Options. That is a better way in my opinion. And if this is an office environment then macro settings can be controlled by the IT department :)

Comment: The problem is, I am really facing a paranoid customer here and try to harden the application against lusers who get told to rename a xlsx to xlsm. Therefore I want the incoming files to be as clean as possible. I already told them to disable macros completely by GP.

Comment: For the sake of being a good answer, you might copy some contents of that link into your answer just in case the site goes offline :)

Comment: Good Point. Done :)